# reload all packages using composer

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

Is it possible to reload all the packages installed using composer? I'm not sure if I made an accidental change to the source of on of the packages, and my app stopped working so I want to rule this out by reloading all the packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generally just wipe the vendor/ directory and then run `composer install` to get everything back from your last known state (stored in composer.lock). Some plugins/custom installers in some frameworks however drop packages outside the vendor dir, but as far as I know with Laravel you should be ok doing this.

Answer (score -1):

I think `php artisan dump-autoload`  should help.