# syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' using @include in blade view

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have these views:

```
- /app/views/hello.blade.php
- /app/views/bye.blade.php
```

In controller I do this:

```
$this->layout->content = \View::make('hello');
```

In `hello.blade.php` I have this:

```
Saying<br>
@include('bye')
```

In `bye.blade.php` I have this:

```
<strong>bye</strong>
```

Using `@include` throws the exception:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_PARSE)
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'

/var/www/html/laravel/app/storage/views/706465d8306e75c61fc49b077329c696:
<?php echo $__env->make('bye', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))); ?>
```

However, if I change the content of `hello.blade.php` to this, everything works fine:

```
Saying<br>
{{ \View::make('bye')->render() }}
```

am I missing something?

**Update 1:**

Verifying and changing `Line Separator` as reported here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23137421/1424329 looks like is not this case because actually the value is `windows eof` format.

**Update 2:**

My last move was to review the  [framework / src / Illuminate / View / Compilers / BladeCompiler.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php)
 file, specifically the fuction that compiles the `@include`:

```
/**
* Compile the include statements into valid PHP.
*
* @param string $expression
* @return string
*/
protected function compileInclude($expression)
{
    if (starts_with($expression, '('))
    {
        $expression = substr($expression, 1, -1);
    }

    return "<?php echo \$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>";
}
```

Guess what? The original source differs from mine. This is my `compileInclude` fuction:

```
protected function compileInclude($expression)
{
    if (starts_with($expression, '('))
    {
        $expression = substr($expression, 1, -1);
    }

    return "<?php echo \$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))); ?>";
}
```

Then, how can be this possible? I will investigate this change and how could be done. For the moment, I would like to know how to pull original laravel's source to my project using composer?

Comment: Here, try this on for size => `<?php echo $__env->make('bye', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path'))); ?>` - One bracket too many, as the error told you `syntax error, unexpected ')'`

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123, according to [Laravel's doc](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates), semi column `;` is not necessary.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is automatically generated template file, as I understand.

Comment: @Cheery Either way, there's a bracket too many.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, as Cheery say, it is generated code.

Comment: probably the syntax error is in the file you are including

Comment: what is in the view you are including?

Comment: @manix read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125662/laravel-blade-include-error-syntax-error-unexpected `it switched from 'edit/EOL conversion/windows format' to 'edit/EOL conversion/Mac format'. And apparently, Laravel doesn't Mac format at all!`

Comment: @Cheery, very rare, because actually I am using `Unix format` type. However, changed it to `windows` does not affect the result.

Comment: @manix can you upload those file? there is definitely something wrong with them. Just made everything the same way - it works normally.

Comment: Try using in your controller instead of layout property `return View::make('hello');` just to display this view

Comment: @Cheery, I found the error source, I think. See edited question.

Comment: @manix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998382/reload-all-packages-using-composer

Comment: @Cherry, if you want you can compile your comments into an answer in order to accept it.